# Getting individual Pandas dataframes instead of 1 dataframe from nested JSON. PYTHON

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested

First, i'm new to coding. I've only been doing this for a couple of months. However, I have been stuck on this for a few days. I am trying to add information from a nested json to a pandas DataFrame, but I get this as a result.

```
        Bid   Strike_Price      Symbol        Exp_Date   
0  17.38      469.0     SPY_033122C469  1648756800000
    Bid   Strike_Price      Symbol        Exp_Date   
0  16.72      470.0     SPY_033122C470  1648756800000
    Bid   Strike_Price      Symbol        Exp_Date   
0  16.07      471.0     SPY_033122C471  1648756800000
    Bid   Strike_Price      Symbol        Exp_Date   
0  15.43      472.0     SPY_033122C472  1648756800000
    Bid  Strike_Price      Symbol        Exp_Date   
0  14.8      473.0     SPY_033122C473  1648756800000
    Bid   Strike_Price      Symbol        Exp_Date   
0  19.02      469.0     SPY_041422C469  1649966400000
    Bid   Strike_Price      Symbol        Exp_Date   
0  18.37      470.0     SPY_041422C470  1649966400000
    Bid   Strike_Price      Symbol        Exp_Date   
0  17.72      471.0     SPY_041422C471  1649966400000
    Bid   Strike_Price      Symbol        Exp_Date   
0  17.08      472.0     SPY_041422C472  1649966400000
    Bid   Strike_Price      Symbol        Exp_Date   
0  16.46      473.0     SPY_041422C473  1649966400000
```

Here is an example of the nested JSON.

```
{
    "symbol": "SPY",
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "underlying": {
        "symbol": "SPY",
        "description": "SPDR S&P 500",
        "change": 2.91,
        "percentChange": 0.62,
        "close": 467.69,
        "quoteTime": 1640307600976,
        "tradeTime": 1640307600001,
        "bid": 470.52,
        "ask": 470.6,
        "last": 470.6,
        "mark": 470.6,
        "markChange": 2.91,
        "markPercentChange": 0.62,
        "bidSize": 300,
        "askSize": 700,
        "highPrice": 472.19,
        "lowPrice": 468.64,
        "openPrice": 468.75,
        "totalVolume": 56439745,
        "exchangeName": "PAC",
        "fiftyTwoWeekHigh": 473.54,
        "fiftyTwoWeekLow": 364.82,
        "delayed": true
    },
    "strategy": "SINGLE",
    "interval": 0.0,
    "isDelayed": true,
    "isIndex": false,
    "interestRate": 0.1,
    "underlyingPrice": 470.56,
    "volatility": 29.0,
    "daysToExpiration": 0.0,
    "numberOfContracts": 10,
    "putExpDateMap": {},
    "callExpDateMap": {
        "2022-03-31:97": {
            "469.0": [
                {
                    "putCall": "CALL",
                    "symbol": "SPY_033122C469",
                    "description": "SPY Mar 31 2022 469 Call (Quarterly)",
                    "exchangeName": "OPR",
                    "bid": 17.38,
                    "ask": 17.48,
                    "last": 17.6,
                    "mark": 17.43,
                    "bidSize": 17,
                    "askSize": 20,
                    "bidAskSize": "17X20",
                    "lastSize": 0,
                    "highPrice": 17.71,
                    "lowPrice": 16.93,
                    "openPrice": 0.0,
                    "closePrice": 15.99,
                    "totalVolume": 52,
                    "tradeDate": null,
                    "tradeTimeInLong": 1640282675820,
                    "quoteTimeInLong": 1640294094808,
                    "netChange": 1.61,
                    "volatility": 17.334,
                    "delta": 0.528,
                    "gamma": 0.009,
                    "theta": -0.083,
                    "vega": 0.972,
                    "rho": 0.596,
                    "openInterest": 474,
                    "timeValue": 16.0,
                    "theoreticalOptionValue": 17.436,
                    "theoreticalVolatility": 29.0,
                    "optionDeliverablesList": null,
                    "strikePrice": 469.0,
                    "expirationDate": 1648756800000,
                    "daysToExpiration": 97,
                    "expirationType": "Q",
                    "lastTradingDay": 1648771200000,
                    "multiplier": 100.0,
                    "settlementType": " ",
                    "deliverableNote": "",
                    "isIndexOption": null,
                    "percentChange": 10.07,
                    "markChange": 1.44,
                    "markPercentChange": 9.04,
                    "intrinsicValue": 1.6,
                    "nonStandard": false,
                    "mini": false,
                    "inTheMoney": true,
                    "pennyPilot": true
                }
            ],
            "470.0": [
                {
                    "putCall": "CALL",
                    "symbol": "SPY_033122C470",
                    "description": "SPY Mar 31 2022 470 Call (Quarterly)",
                    "exchangeName": "OPR",
                    "bid": 16.72,
                    "ask": 16.82,
                    "last": 17.0,
                    "mark": 16.77,
                    "bidSize": 17,
                    "askSize": 20,
                    "bidAskSize": "17X20",
                    "lastSize": 0,
                    "highPrice": 17.47,
                    "lowPrice": 16.43,
                    "openPrice": 0.0,
                    "closePrice": 15.35,
                    "totalVolume": 124,
                    "tradeDate": null,
                    "tradeTimeInLong": 1640293092011,
                    "quoteTimeInLong": 1640294098603,
                    "netChange": 1.65,
                    "volatility": 17.162,
                    "delta": 0.519,
                    "gamma": 0.01,
                    "theta": -0.082,
                    "vega": 0.974,
                    "rho": 0.588,
                    "openInterest": 1260,
                    "timeValue": 16.4,
                    "theoreticalOptionValue": 16.78,
                    "theoreticalVolatility": 29.0,
                    "optionDeliverablesList": null,
                    "strikePrice": 470.0,
                    "expirationDate": 1648756800000,
                    "daysToExpiration": 97,
                    "expirationType": "Q",
                    "lastTradingDay": 1648771200000,
                    "multiplier": 100.0,
                    "settlementType": " ",
                    "deliverableNote": "",
                    "isIndexOption": null,
                    "percentChange": 10.75,
                    "markChange": 1.42,
                    "markPercentChange": 9.25,
                    "intrinsicValue": 0.6,
                    "nonStandard": false,
                    "mini": false,
                    "inTheMoney": true,
                    "pennyPilot": true
                }
            ],
            "471.0": [
                {
                    "putCall": "CALL",
                    "symbol": "SPY_033122C471",
                    "description": "SPY Mar 31 2022 471 Call (Quarterly)",
                    "exchangeName": "OPR",
                    "bid": 16.07,
                    "ask": 16.17,
                    "last": 16.75,
                    "mark": 16.12,
                    "bidSize": 17,
                    "askSize": 20,
                    "bidAskSize": "17X20",
                    "lastSize": 0,
                    "highPrice": 16.75,
                    "lowPrice": 15.8,
                    "openPrice": 0.0,
                    "closePrice": 14.73,
                    "totalVolume": 22,
                    "tradeDate": null,
                    "tradeTimeInLong": 1640292441039,
                    "quoteTimeInLong": 1640294094808,
                    "netChange": 2.03,
                    "volatility": 16.976,
                    "delta": 0.509,
                    "gamma": 0.01,
                    "theta": -0.081,
                    "vega": 0.974,
                    "rho": 0.579,
                    "openInterest": 314,
                    "timeValue": 16.75,
                    "theoreticalOptionValue": 16.12,
                    "theoreticalVolatility": 29.0,
                    "optionDeliverablesList": null,
                    "strikePrice": 471.0,
                    "expirationDate": 1648756800000,
                    "daysToExpiration": 97,
                    "expirationType": "Q",
                    "lastTradingDay": 1648771200000,
                    "multiplier": 100.0,
                    "settlementType": " ",
                    "deliverableNote": "",
                    "isIndexOption": null,
                    "percentChange": 13.75,
                    "markChange": 1.39,
                    "markPercentChange": 9.47,
                    "intrinsicValue": -0.4,
                    "nonStandard": false,
                    "mini": false,
                    "inTheMoney": false,
                    "pennyPilot": true
                }
            ],
            "472.0": [
                {
                    "putCall": "CALL",
                    "symbol": "SPY_033122C472",
                    "description": "SPY Mar 31 2022 472 Call (Quarterly)",
                    "exchangeName": "OPR",
                    "bid": 15.43,
                    "ask": 15.53,
                    "last": 15.49,
                    "mark": 15.48,
                    "bidSize": 17,
                    "askSize": 20,
                    "bidAskSize": "17X20",
                    "lastSize": 0,
                    "highPrice": 15.97,
                    "lowPrice": 15.12,
                    "openPrice": 0.0,
                    "closePrice": 14.12,
                    "totalVolume": 18,
                    "tradeDate": null,
                    "tradeTimeInLong": 1640293822217,
                    "quoteTimeInLong": 1640294098608,
                    "netChange": 1.37,
                    "volatility": 16.801,
                    "delta": 0.499,
                    "gamma": 0.01,
                    "theta": -0.081,
                    "vega": 0.975,
                    "rho": 0.569,
                    "openInterest": 295,
                    "timeValue": 15.49,
                    "theoreticalOptionValue": 15.48,
                    "theoreticalVolatility": 29.0,
                    "optionDeliverablesList": null,
                    "strikePrice": 472.0,
                    "expirationDate": 1648756800000,
                    "daysToExpiration": 97,
                    "expirationType": "Q",
                    "lastTradingDay": 1648771200000,
                    "multiplier": 100.0,
                    "settlementType": " ",
                    "deliverableNote": "",
                    "isIndexOption": null,
                    "percentChange": 9.7,
                    "markChange": 1.36,
                    "markPercentChange": 9.63,
                    "intrinsicValue": -1.4,
                    "nonStandard": false,
                    "mini": false,
                    "inTheMoney": false,
                    "pennyPilot": true
                }
            ],
            "473.0": [
                {
                    "putCall": "CALL",
                    "symbol": "SPY_033122C473",
                    "description": "SPY Mar 31 2022 473 Call (Quarterly)",
                    "exchangeName": "OPR",
                    "bid": 14.8,
                    "ask": 14.9,
                    "last": 15.12,
                    "mark": 14.85,
                    "bidSize": 17,
                    "askSize": 20,
                    "bidAskSize": "17X20",
                    "lastSize": 0,
                    "highPrice": 15.12,
                    "lowPrice": 14.87,
                    "openPrice": 0.0,
                    "closePrice": 13.52,
                    "totalVolume": 23,
                    "tradeDate": null,
                    "tradeTimeInLong": 1640285417120,
                    "quoteTimeInLong": 1640294098608,
                    "netChange": 1.6,
                    "volatility": 16.626,
                    "delta": 0.489,
                    "gamma": 0.01,
                    "theta": -0.08,
                    "vega": 0.974,
                    "rho": 0.56,
                    "openInterest": 645,
                    "timeValue": 15.12,
                    "theoreticalOptionValue": 14.85,
                    "theoreticalVolatility": 29.0,
                    "optionDeliverablesList": null,
                    "strikePrice": 473.0,
                    "expirationDate": 1648756800000,
                    "daysToExpiration": 97,
                    "expirationType": "Q",
                    "lastTradingDay": 1648771200000,
                    "multiplier": 100.0,
                    "settlementType": " ",
                    "deliverableNote": "",
                    "isIndexOption": null,
                    "percentChange": 11.83,
                    "markChange": 1.33,
                    "markPercentChange": 9.84,
                    "intrinsicValue": -2.4,
                    "nonStandard": false,
                    "mini": false,
                    "inTheMoney": false,
                    "pennyPilot": true
                }
            ]
        },
        "2022-04-14:111": {
            "469.0": [
                {
                    "putCall": "CALL",
                    "symbol": "SPY_041422C469",
                    "description": "SPY Apr 14 2022 469 Call",
                    "exchangeName": "OPR",
                    "bid": 19.02,
                    "ask": 19.12,
                    "last": 19.16,
                    "mark": 19.11,
                    "bidSize": 20,
                    "askSize": 20,
                    "bidAskSize": "20X20",
                    "lastSize": 0,
                    "highPrice": 19.89,
                    "lowPrice": 18.77,
                    "openPrice": 0.0,
                    "closePrice": 17.61,
                    "totalVolume": 522,
                    "tradeDate": null,
                    "tradeTimeInLong": 1640293703687,
                    "quoteTimeInLong": 1640294095144,
                    "netChange": 1.54,
                    "volatility": 17.785,
                    "delta": 0.53,
                    "gamma": 0.009,
                    "theta": -0.08,
                    "vega": 1.039,
                    "rho": 0.679,
                    "openInterest": 1144,
                    "timeValue": 17.56,
                    "theoreticalOptionValue": 19.108,
                    "theoreticalVolatility": 29.0,
                    "optionDeliverablesList": null,
                    "strikePrice": 469.0,
                    "expirationDate": 1649966400000,
                    "daysToExpiration": 111,
                    "expirationType": "R",
                    "lastTradingDay": 1649980800000,
                    "multiplier": 100.0,
                    "settlementType": " ",
                    "deliverableNote": "",
                    "isIndexOption": null,
                    "percentChange": 8.77,
                    "markChange": 1.49,
                    "markPercentChange": 8.47,
                    "intrinsicValue": 1.6,
                    "nonStandard": false,
                    "mini": false,
                    "inTheMoney": true,
                    "pennyPilot": true
                }
            ],
            "470.0": [
                {
                    "putCall": "CALL",
                    "symbol": "SPY_041422C470",
                    "description": "SPY Apr 14 2022 470 Call",
                    "exchangeName": "OPR",
                    "bid": 18.37,
                    "ask": 18.47,
                    "last": 18.72,
                    "mark": 18.4,
                    "bidSize": 17,
                    "askSize": 20,
                    "bidAskSize": "17X20",
                    "lastSize": 0,
                    "highPrice": 18.95,
                    "lowPrice": 18.1,
                    "openPrice": 0.0,
                    "closePrice": 17.0,
                    "totalVolume": 112,
                    "tradeDate": null,
                    "tradeTimeInLong": 1640292936466,
                    "quoteTimeInLong": 1640294098604,
                    "netChange": 1.73,
                    "volatility": 17.578,
                    "delta": 0.521,
                    "gamma": 0.009,
                    "theta": -0.079,
                    "vega": 1.04,
                    "rho": 0.67,
                    "openInterest": 949,
                    "timeValue": 18.12,
                    "theoreticalOptionValue": 18.406,
                    "theoreticalVolatility": 29.0,
                    "optionDeliverablesList": null,
                    "strikePrice": 470.0,
                    "expirationDate": 1649966400000,
                    "daysToExpiration": 111,
                    "expirationType": "R",
                    "lastTradingDay": 1649980800000,
                    "multiplier": 100.0,
                    "settlementType": " ",
                    "deliverableNote": "",
                    "isIndexOption": null,
                    "percentChange": 10.15,
                    "markChange": 1.4,
                    "markPercentChange": 8.25,
                    "intrinsicValue": 0.6,
                    "nonStandard": false,
                    "mini": false,
                    "inTheMoney": true,
                    "pennyPilot": true
                }
            ],
            "471.0": [
                {
                    "putCall": "CALL",
                    "symbol": "SPY_041422C471",
                    "description": "SPY Apr 14 2022 471 Call",
                    "exchangeName": "OPR",
                    "bid": 17.72,
                    "ask": 17.82,
                    "last": 17.8,
                    "mark": 17.77,
                    "bidSize": 25,
                    "askSize": 20,
                    "bidAskSize": "25X20",
                    "lastSize": 0,
                    "highPrice": 18.42,
                    "lowPrice": 17.69,
                    "openPrice": 0.0,
                    "closePrice": 16.38,
                    "totalVolume": 101,
                    "tradeDate": null,
                    "tradeTimeInLong": 1640293185215,
                    "quoteTimeInLong": 1640294098603,
                    "netChange": 1.42,
                    "volatility": 17.423,
                    "delta": 0.512,
                    "gamma": 0.009,
                    "theta": -0.079,
                    "vega": 1.041,
                    "rho": 0.661,
                    "openInterest": 435,
                    "timeValue": 17.8,
                    "theoreticalOptionValue": 17.767,
                    "theoreticalVolatility": 29.0,
                    "optionDeliverablesList": null,
                    "strikePrice": 471.0,
                    "expirationDate": 1649966400000,
                    "daysToExpiration": 111,
                    "expirationType": "R",
                    "lastTradingDay": 1649980800000,
                    "multiplier": 100.0,
                    "settlementType": " ",
                    "deliverableNote": "",
                    "isIndexOption": null,
                    "percentChange": 8.7,
                    "markChange": 1.39,
                    "markPercentChange": 8.5,
                    "intrinsicValue": -0.4,
                    "nonStandard": false,
                    "mini": false,
                    "inTheMoney": false,
                    "pennyPilot": true
                }
            ],
            "472.0": [
                {
                    "putCall": "CALL",
                    "symbol": "SPY_041422C472",
                    "description": "SPY Apr 14 2022 472 Call",
                    "exchangeName": "OPR",
                    "bid": 17.08,
                    "ask": 17.18,
                    "last": 17.81,
                    "mark": 17.14,
                    "bidSize": 17,
                    "askSize": 20,
                    "bidAskSize": "17X20",
                    "lastSize": 0,
                    "highPrice": 17.81,
                    "lowPrice": 16.22,
                    "openPrice": 0.0,
                    "closePrice": 15.76,
                    "totalVolume": 74,
                    "tradeDate": null,
                    "tradeTimeInLong": 1640292857129,
                    "quoteTimeInLong": 1640294094807,
                    "netChange": 2.06,
                    "volatility": 17.269,
                    "delta": 0.503,
                    "gamma": 0.009,
                    "theta": -0.078,
                    "vega": 1.042,
                    "rho": 0.651,
                    "openInterest": 170,
                    "timeValue": 17.81,
                    "theoreticalOptionValue": 17.136,
                    "theoreticalVolatility": 29.0,
                    "optionDeliverablesList": null,
                    "strikePrice": 472.0,
                    "expirationDate": 1649966400000,
                    "daysToExpiration": 111,
                    "expirationType": "R",
                    "lastTradingDay": 1649980800000,
                    "multiplier": 100.0,
                    "settlementType": " ",
                    "deliverableNote": "",
                    "isIndexOption": null,
                    "percentChange": 13.04,
                    "markChange": 1.38,
                    "markPercentChange": 8.77,
                    "intrinsicValue": -1.4,
                    "nonStandard": false,
                    "mini": false,
                    "inTheMoney": false,
                    "pennyPilot": true
                }
            ],
            "473.0": [
                {
                    "putCall": "CALL",
                    "symbol": "SPY_041422C473",
                    "description": "SPY Apr 14 2022 473 Call",
                    "exchangeName": "OPR",
                    "bid": 16.46,
                    "ask": 16.55,
                    "last": 17.15,
                    "mark": 16.51,
                    "bidSize": 17,
                    "askSize": 20,
                    "bidAskSize": "17X20",
                    "lastSize": 0,
                    "highPrice": 17.15,
                    "lowPrice": 16.3,
                    "openPrice": 0.0,
                    "closePrice": 15.14,
                    "totalVolume": 663,
                    "tradeDate": null,
                    "tradeTimeInLong": 1640292600017,
                    "quoteTimeInLong": 1640294095144,
                    "netChange": 2.01,
                    "volatility": 17.106,
                    "delta": 0.494,
                    "gamma": 0.009,
                    "theta": -0.077,
                    "vega": 1.042,
                    "rho": 0.641,
                    "openInterest": 238,
                    "timeValue": 17.15,
                    "theoreticalOptionValue": 16.506,
                    "theoreticalVolatility": 29.0,
                    "optionDeliverablesList": null,
                    "strikePrice": 473.0,
                    "expirationDate": 1649966400000,
                    "daysToExpiration": 111,
                    "expirationType": "R",
                    "lastTradingDay": 1649980800000,
                    "multiplier": 100.0,
                    "settlementType": " ",
                    "deliverableNote": "",
                    "isIndexOption": null,
                    "percentChange": 13.28,
                    "markChange": 1.37,
                    "markPercentChange": 9.02,
                    "intrinsicValue": -2.4,
                    "nonStandard": false,
                    "mini": false,
                    "inTheMoney": false,
                    "pennyPilot": true
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have tried.

```
for value in data['callExpDateMap']:#Gets expiration dates [callExpDateMap][Bid]
    for k in data['callExpDateMap'][value]:#Allows me to iterate through nested objects without knowing them. [callExpDateMap][Bid]
        for v in data['callExpDateMap'][value][k]:#Gets me to the symbol, bid and strike price, etc
            df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Bid","Strike_Price","Symbol","Exp_Date"]) #Setting up columns
            
            df1 = (v['bid'])
            df2 = (v['strikePrice'])
            df3 = (v['symbol'])
            df4 = (v['expirationDate'])
            
            df = df.append({'Bid' : df1,#Appending variables to the columns
                            'Strike_Price' : df2,
                            'Symbol' : df3,
                            'Exp_Date' : df4,
                            }, ignore_index=True)
            pd.set_option('colheader_justify', 'center') # Indents and makes the columns pretty

            print(df)
```

The information that I want is the Bid, Strike Price, Symbol and Expiration Date from the 4th layer in the json. The Second and Third layer is dynamic as it will change. Then I need to be able to sort through them via columns until I get the variable I need. Can anyone help me fix this so that I get one dataframe. I'm a new to this. I can't really list what I have tried already, as i've tried many random things over the last few days. I'm just stuck! I apologize for the poor question. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler solution would be to extract all the actual data objects (the ones with the `bid` property) and put them in list. The `pd.DataFrame()` function can take a list of objects (`dict`s) and make a nice dataframe out of it:

```
objs = []
for v1 in data['callExpDateMap'].values():
    for v2 in v1.values():
        objs.extend(v2)

df = pd.DataFrame(objs)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  putCall      symbol                  description              exchangeName   bid    ask   last  mark   ...  percentChange  markChange markPercentChange  intrinsicValue  nonStandard  mini   inTheMoney  pennyPilot
0   CALL   SPY_033122C469  SPY Mar 31 2022 469 Call (Quarterly)      OPR      17.38  17.48  17.6  17.43  ...      10.07         1.44           9.04              1.6          False     False     True        True   
1   CALL   SPY_033122C470  SPY Mar 31 2022 470 Call (Quarterly)      OPR      16.72  16.82  17.0  16.77  ...      10.75         1.42           9.25              0.6          False     False     True        True   

[2 rows x 49 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been pulling my hair out for days! I appreciate your help! This is it!

Comment: You're welcome! _I've been pulling my hair out for days!_ - That's the time to come to SO :)